# How is energy defined in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation

I have been introduced to QM this spring semester. One thing that I couldn't understand is that how do they define the energy of an electron.

For example while solving "Particle in a box" problem my teacher said that *note that the energy we are using in Schrodinger's equation is no more equal to the Kinetic plus the potential energy* because these terms are vague in QM.

But then if we use the analogy with photons, we associate its energy to its frequency but there we have an oscillating electric and magnetic field so talking about frequency kind of makes sense. Here we don't have anything as such that is oscillating.

**So what exactly do we mean by the energy of a quantum particle ?**

Comment: What do you mean with position, momentum and so on?

Answer (score 0):

It is still K.E plus potential energy at the elementary level (non relativitic). You do have an oscillating wave function. If you take its double derivative you get the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

So as SAKhan mentioned on an elementary particle description energy in QM is still composed of kinetic and potential energy. However both of them will be operator-valued, the expressions will stay similar to the classical ones but the position and momentum of the particles would be operators. The energy will then be described by a Hamilton Operator e.g for a single particle with mass m in external potential V:

$$
\hat{H} = \hat{T} + \hat{V} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} +  V(\hat{r})
$$

To then derive at scalar physical quantities you do have to calculate the quantum mechanical expectation value (or for more detail the distribution function) of your observable, in the case of energy.

$$
\left\langle\hat{H}\right\rangle = \int_{r^3} \langle
r|\hat{H}|r\rangle d^3r = \int_{p^3} \langle
p|\hat{H}|p\rangle d^3p
$$

where $|r\rangle$ \ $|p\rangle$  are position \ momentum eigenstates.

Note that trying to evaluate the last expression in momentum basis will lead to the occurrence of expressions of the form

$$
\langle r| p\rangle = constant \cdot e^{ipx/\hbar},
$$

which as for their spacial dependency are plainwaves with a wavelength of $\frac{h}{p}$. So you really do end up in quite a similar situation as with light in terms of oscillating fields, when it comes to the momentum wavelength connection. However the energy-wavelength relation will be different from a photons one even for a free particle, due to light using the relativistic edge-case-dispersion relation ($T \sim p$), while your particle will use the classical dispersion relation ($T \sim p^2$).