# What is the physical meaning of kinetic energy in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

Literally, what would be the physical meaning of kinetic energy in quantum mechanics?

There is kinetic energy operator term even in time-independent Schrodinger equation.
And this operator and wavefunction will give energy eigenvalue. Can I just say this quantity is related to the probability of the particle?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/805590/2451

Comment: Does this question really deserve down votes? Clearly there is some confusion about the concepts. Asking for clarification should be encouraged.

Comment: Isolating and suppressing the potential yields a free particle, whose energy is the kinetic energy, no?

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics, the concept of energy comes when a constant of movement can be identified in some systems, as an orbital trajectory or an harmonic oscillator. We can get this quantity, the Hamiltonian, by applying the second law of Newton for conservative forces, and making dot products with the infinitesimal displacement.

In quantum mechanics, the equivalent of a constant of movement is the eigenvalue of a differential operator, the Hamiltonian. In the case of a free particle, the differential operator is simpler, but it is the same idea.

Comment: Thank you. The example you provided really helps me understand.
I misunderstood in a way; 1) 'constant movement' equals 'translational motion' and 2) a time-independent equation means there is no net translational motion. But, as you mentioned, it can include motions such as harmonic oscillation or trajectory. Not so sure if I properly understand what you mean though..

Comment: Constant of movement is for example the sum $gh + \frac{1}{2}v^2$ in a simple pendulum with low amplitude. It is always moving, but this sum keeps constant all the time.